# Обфускация Javascript на ходу на PHP

Tags: javascript, php, защита, обфускация

Пользователи подключают мой скрипт вида `<script src="//domain.com/user-uuid/script.js"></script>` на свой сайт. PHP по шаблону генерирует **на ходу** скрипт для них (в зависимости от настроек и множества других условий).

На днях встала тема защиты скрипта, скрипт платный и стоит денег, вся логика находится на front-end, скопировать не составляет трудности. До недавних пор полагался лишь на [секрет неуловимого Джо](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE).

Какие варианты у меня:

- CLI-утилиты типа [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator).
  **Плюс**: очень качественная обфускация, с множеством защит от деобфускации.
  **Минус**: сравнительно медленный и не работает на простом shared-хостинге
- Простое шифрование кода каким-то алгоритмом и исполнение через `eval`.
  **Плюс**: скорость такая, как нужно.
  **Минус**: очнь легко обойти - если заменить `eval` на `console.log`, недоброжелатель тут же получит расшифрованый код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, у меня была довольно специфическая структура проекта, `JS-код` генерировался на ходу с помощью `PHP`. Нужно было обфусцировать код, но оставить возможность добавлять некоторые данные на ходу на PHP.

Сейчас расскажу как я решил эту проблему.

> TL;DR:
> Я локально переобфусцирую код и кладу его в соседнюю папку после изменений.

Во-первых, я подключил Webpack. Части, которые раньше вставлялись на `PHP` теперь подключаются с помощью `require`. Так же это позитивно сказалось на структуре кода проекта.
Я подключил [Webpack-плагин](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator#readme) для известного обфускатора [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator).

"Динамичные" данные, которые должны вставлятся с помощью PHP, я вставляю в виде переменных типа `__$$CONFIG$$__` и `__$$IS_DEV$$__`, которые с помощью PHP заменялись на ходу на JSON-массив или код. Таким же образом заменялись некоторые данные в строковых литералах. Эти строки и идентификаторы я добавил в список исключений, чтоб обфускатор их не переименовал.

После изменений я делаю `npm build` и потом делаю коммит, в котором в одной папке изменения в исходниках, а в другой - в обфусцированной сборке. А потом cron-скрипт подтягивает обновление из GitHub на хостинг.